# Flutter How to add multiple pages on one page

Tags: flutter

[image]

Hello and thank you in advance..
I am new to flutter and i want to make screen which i shown u...! Just look at the picture..i marked red color in that pic i have circle avater and when i tap on each i need to show there data on same page...no need to navigate to another screen...! Show that data on same page...! Plz help me provide me if there code u have

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work, you're basically creating your widget tree in a declarative way in flutter, the column will allow you to stack two separate widgets (your list and your grid). I recommend going through a few tutorials (starting here: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab)on building an app, flutter comes really easy, then watch all the videos created by the flutter team on the different widgets. Everything is a widget and you will use each kind of widget to build your ui.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      Positioned(
          top: 20,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ListView(
                children: [/*circle images*/],
              ),
              GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 10,
                children: [/*profile images*/],
              )
            ],
          ))
    ]);
  }
```